# Can we call ASP.NET webservice without soap envelop? Like a simple REST api

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest, web-services

Can we create a simple post method in ASP.NET web service which runs like a REST API method?

Because I don't want to provide an envelop for post and get request.

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Comment: So you want to make a new rest api,  or add to an existing soap service?  New rest api can be done easy enough, no idea if you could add this to an existing service

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "web service"? Do you mean an action method in ASP.NET Web API or MVC? Or do you mean a method marked with the WebService attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you do this, but in fact, if you create a web method in .net, right out of the box:

```
It can accept soap 1.1, 1.2 - no extra code on your part
It can accept a rest call - even json data - no extra code on your part
It can accept a plane jane URL (again rest) call - no extra code on your part
```

So, in fact, you get all 3 of the above - in fact the above counts as 4, since your ajax call can use (data) or the URL to pass the information.

Say, I add a I create a web service page like this:

[image]

Do note, you don't HAVE to crate a web service page, you can drop into a EXISTING page a function (returns values), or drop in a sub into that page. As long as you ta the function/sub with WebMethod(), then you are good to go.

So, with above page, lets add a simple function. It will take a paramter FirstName, and LastName, and return the full name.

So, we have this code in the above web service page:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function GetName(FirstName As String, LastName As String) As String

    Dim sResult As String = ""

    sResult = FirstName & " " & LastName

    Return sResult

End Function
```

Above is VERY simple.

So, you can use jQuery, and call this method via post like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cSoap" runat="server" Text="Soap Example" 
            OnClientClick="webcalltest();return false" />

        <script>

            function webcalltest() {

                var First = 'Albert'
                var Last = 'Kallal'

            var url = '../WebService1.asmx/GetName'
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ FirstName: First, LastName: Last }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d)
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText);
                }
            });
```

As noted, that web method will also accept soap calls.

And you can even skip the headers (in the above post), and toss out a 100% plane jane REST call - just the URL, say like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Soap Example" 
            OnClientClick="webtest2();return false" />

        <script>
            function webtest2() {

                var First = 'Albert'
                var Last = 'Kallal'
                var url = '../WebService1.asmx/GetName?FirstName=' + First + '&LastName=' + Last

                $.get(url, function (data, status) {

                    alert($(data).find('string').text())

                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                })
            }

        </script>
```

So, in above, we just used the URL for the rest call. (and did not set up any headers, or even a soap xml record). So, just keep in mind, even older legacy soap methods in most cases can be passed and consume JSON data - and you in general don't have to re-write or even change the web methods.

And as above shows, you can just feed the URL with the parameters, and not pass any headers at all - let alone the soap ones.